# How to read data from sqlite .db file in HTML 5/cordova/Intel xdk

Tags: android, html, sqlite, cordova, intel-xdk

I am working with intel XDK and there I have a prepopulated .db file which i need to read inside my code. As we do in native app where we put db files in assets directory and then access those database by copying them in app's database directory. I am new to hybrid apps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did it with sql.js and xml http request using following piece of code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'yourDBname.db', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function(e) 
{ 
mId = sessionStorage.i;
var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(this.response);
var db = new SQL.Database(uInt8Array);
var contents = db.exec("SELECT * FROM ....your query");
// Do as per requirment
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NB: For view DB created by your project ,
1st take a windows build and run your project .

Then go to 
C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Packages\pakagename\LocalState\yourdbname.db

You can find your DB file 
you can view that file [on this site](http://sqliteviewer.flowsoft7.com/)

For database creation and usage
Please use the link to the Intel XDK third party plugin. Before that please download the project dependency jar file from GitHub and create the directory with Cordova plugin SQLite name and place the file in it, include the jar file. Then try to add the plugin using URL .

See the whole code below
1.create database
2.add table
3.add data to table
4.get data from table

```
> // Wait for Cordova to load
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    alert("Start ");
    var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'my.db', location: 'default' }, function () {


     alert("database creatred");
     db.transaction(function (tx) {
         tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE customerAccounts (firstname, lastname, acctNo)');
         alert("Table create");

         addItem("first", "last", 100);
         getData("last");

     }, function (error) {
         alert('transaction error: ' + error.message);
     }, function () {
        alert('transaction ok');
     });


    }, function (error) {
    });

 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   


function addItem(first, last, acctNum) {
  alert("start adding");
    db.transaction(function (tx) {

        var query = "INSERT INTO customerAccounts (firstname, lastname, acctNo) VALUES (?,?,?)";
          alert("start insterting");
        tx.executeSql(query, [first, last, acctNum], function(tx, res) {
            console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId + " -- probably 1");
            console.log("rowsAffected: " + res.rowsAffected + " -- should be 1");
            alert("insert complete");
        },
        function(tx, error) {
            alert('INSERT error: ' + error.message);
        });
    }, function(error) {
        alert('transaction error: ' + error.message);
    }, function() {
        alert('transaction ok');
    });
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

    function getData(last) {

    db.transaction(function (tx) {
          alert("get data");
        var query = "SELECT firstname, lastname, acctNo FROM customerAccounts WHERE lastname = ?";
           alert("get data working");
        tx.executeSql(query, [last], function (tx, resultSet) {

            for(var x = 0; x < resultSet.rows.length; x++) {
                alert("First name: " + resultSet.rows.item(x).firstname +
                    ", Acct: " + resultSet.rows.item(x).acctNo);
            }
        },
        function (tx, error) {
            alert('SELECT error: ' + error.message);
        });
    }, function (error) {
        alert('transaction error: ' + error.message);
    }, function () {
        alert('transaction ok');
    });
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    

}
```

Comment: I asked for prepopulated sqlite databse, this solution is for creating new database and to use that.